# Excel VBA Filter Out One Value, Then Delete Visible Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code, and what I am trying to do is filter out an employee's name, and then delete all the visible rows which presumably contain the data for all other employees, then show the first employee's data.  I have used the MsgBox feature to debug, and that returns the proper value for the employee.  I have also used the step through tool, and what I am noticing is the AutoFilter is added, then when I check the filter in column B none of the employees are checked, then no rows get deleted.  Any help with this code would be greatly appreciated, as I am sure I am missing something silly.

```
'Filter out the employee name, and delete visible rows down to the last row in column A
With Range("A4:DZ" & lastRow)
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & empName, Operator:=xlAnd
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With

'Unfilter the sheet
Worksheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData
```

Comment: Is it possible that either of `empName`, or the values in the cells, contain additional whitespace such as leading/trailling spaces, in which case `empName` wouldn't match any values, and that would exhibit the behavior you describe.

Comment: No - but I did think of that.  Plus, there are some Sumif formulas in the workbook that work off of both values and would not work if that was the case.

Comment: This code is absolutely working when I test it, though... can you provide some example data that exhibits this problem?

Comment: Can you remove the `Operator` portion and try again? Since the issue is with the `.Autofilter` line, that's what I noticed right away - you are using an `Operator` without having two `Criteria`. If that ends up being the solution I'll post as an answer.

Comment: I removed the `Operator`, and that has no effect on the output.  Unfortunately, I can't post any of the data I am using as it is all employee data (confidential).

Comment: Update - so after going through the data line by line, it does look like the rows for `empName` are being filtered out.  However, if I manually check the filter, all employees are unchecked which I believe is why the following line of code is not deleting the visible rows.  Any ideas?